# How do you deploy from Visual Studio to a remote on-prem Service Fabric cluster?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-service-fabric

I have installed a Service Fabric unsecured development cluster on a shared, on-premises VM with firewall turned off. I can connect to it locally (on same VM) via PowerShell, and deploy locally via Visual Studio. However I am unable to connect or deploy to the cluster from any other box on our network, getting the following error message from PowerShell:

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : No cluster endpoint is reachable, please check if there is connectivity/firewall/DNS issue.
```

As I said, the firewall is turned off on the machine hosting the cluster. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is it a one node deployment of Service Fabric you are trying to reach remotely? If so, that's not a supported scenario. You will need to have a real cluster to do remote connections to the management endpoints.

Comment: @Mikkel: By 'one node', do you mean one physical  machine or VM? In this case we are using the default development cluster with five nodes, all running on one machine (VM). It is convenient to have different devs be able to deploy to a shared dev cluster, hence the need to connect to a dev cluster on another machine or VM.

Comment: @MikkelMørkHegnhøj: If remote (over local network) deployment to a default SF dev cluster is not a supported scenario, please provide that as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OneBox deployment of Service Fabric (installed via the SDK) does not support remote publishing.

Template for configuring a shared dev/test cluster consisting of three nodes can be found here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-creation-for-windows-server/#download-the-service-fabric-standalone-package

/Mikkel